# How to load Spring Security dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, camunda

I have an existing vendor product which is written in Spring Boot. I don't have the source code / POM file / build pipeline but I want to implement Spring Security into this.

I know that this product scans for a particular directory lets say `/app/customlibs` for JARs and it also respects the `spring.factories` in `META-INF` and I have added multiple functionalities using this feature.

However since the base product does not have Spring Security dependencies so I am not able to place Spring Security rules, what shall I place in that directory `/app/customlibs` so it can load Spring Security dynamically.
Is this possible to pack all Spring Security JARs together somehow?

I tried placing Spring Security related JARs manually and one custom class which enables security via annotation `@EnableWebSecurity`.

But the application fails to start. Looks like Spring Security related filters are not enabled.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field clientRegistrationRepository in com.example.workflow.config.WebAppSecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Comment: why do you want to add it to the application? You could also use a reverse proxy or a Gateway to handle security. At least for URL-based security.

Comment: @dur The application by default come with basic Auth that can not be overridden without spring security taking over.

Comment: Oh, that's an additional problem, if the application also authenticates. How do you want to disable basic auth in your application if you can't change the code?

Comment: For your logs: It looks like Spring Boot's autoconfigruation for Spring Security is not executed. Show  your security configuration class `WebAppSecurityConfig`. It looks like you are enabled OAuth2.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks All I was able to solve it. This is Camunda-Run product.
Solution :

1. I already had created custom okta plugin jar which contains all my security config , I added following in
   META-INF/spring.factories

`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.example.workflow.config.WebAppSecurityConfig`

2.I had to copy following jars manually in to userlib folder where Camunda scans for jars. I know this is a dirty solution : I am planning to create a POM/BOM project for automatic dependency management.

[image]

I will share GitHub link to my repo once I implement clean solution.

Comment: https://jira.camunda.com/browse/CAM-11308

Comment: https://forum.camunda.io/t/integrate-camunda-platform-run-docker-with-okta/39444/8

Comment: Thanks @rob2universe I have added comments on JIRA. Also I have made progress on this since . Read my post on Camunda forum https://forum.camunda.io/t/integrate-camunda-platform-run-docker-with-okta/39444/8    . I will share my Github repo once I am done with implementation.